# How do I display a date correctly that is stored in the database as a backwards 8 digit number from Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: functions, custom-field, date

I am modifying someone's Wordpress theme and they have a section for upcoming tour dates.  The page for inputting was made with Advanced Custom fields plugin and uses a date picker widget that stores the date as an 8 digit number backwards in the database such as

20140508

and I would like it to display in ANY normal format like

08/05/2014 or even better Aug. 05, 2014

I'm not much of a coder but I can see that the template file just displays it like this:

```
$start_date = get_sub_field('appearance_start_date');

$echo .= '<p>' . $start_date . '</p>';
```

Is there some code I can add to the template file or a pre-made function I could use to display the date in a normal format?

Answer (score 1):

I voted to close your question, because it is pretty much a PHP problem, not a WordPress one and thus off topic on here. Nonetheless here comes some help.

General information about

- [Formatting Date and Time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time)

from the WordPress codex you might find helpful.

Aside from that, on the PHP side of things, the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) function and the [`datetime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class are pretty much what you are after. There are a lot of other things, but those two will give you a good starting point.

One example based on [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php) to follow up on:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Ymd', '20140508' );
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Good luck going from here!